# Best way to stream/logically replicate RDS Postgres data to kinesis

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kinesis

Our primary datastore is an RDS Postgres database. It would be nice if we could stream all changes to that happen in Postgres to some sink - whether that's kinesis, elasticsearch or any other data store.

We use Postgres 9.5 which has support for 'logical replication'. However, all the extensions that tap into this stream are blocked on RDS. There's a tutorial for streaming the MySQL RDS flavor to kinesis - the postgres equivalent would be ideal. Is this possible currently?

Comment: Postgres RDS now supports wal2json replication output as of RDS Postgres 9.5.7 and 9.6.3.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at https://github.com/disneystreaming/pg2k4j . It takes all changes made to your database and streams them to Kinesis. See the README for an example of how to set this up with RDS. We've been using it in production and have found it very useful for solving this exact problem. Disclaimer: I wrote https://github.com/disneystreaming/pg2k4j

Answer (score 3):

Integrate a central Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) for PostgreSQL database with other systems by streaming its modifications into Amazon Kinesis Data Streams. An earlier post, Streaming Changes in a Database with Amazon Kinesis, described how to integrate a central RDS for MySQL database with other systems by streaming modifications through Kinesis. In this post, I take it a step further and explain how to use an AWS Lambda function to capture the changes in Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL and stream those changes to Kinesis Data Streams.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/

Comment: Did you manage to understand what should trigger the Lambda? should it be on a fix interval every few minutes? Thanks

Comment: `cur.consume_stream(consume)` runs continuously, we would need long running instance instead of lambda